# Using maven plugin versions-maven-plugin's <goal>use-latest-releases</goal> for latest releases

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, versions-maven-plugin

Used < goal> **use-latest-releases** </ goal> for newer release(all non-SNAPSHOT) and replaces pom's version with the latest releases.
I have added dependency(on which current project is dependent) in the pom.xml with < version> [anyVersionNumber] < /version>.

When I am running "mvn clean package", build is getting failed with error message
**Could not resolve dependencies for project < sample>:jar:0.1: Could not find artifact < some>:jar:[anyVerionNumber]**

**versions-maven-plugin** supposed to update < version>[anyVersionNumber]</ version> with < version>[latest release]</ version> in my pom.xml.

Any idea how could I get latest release by using this maven plugin?

Comment: First you have to get your build working afterwards you can thing about using versions-maven-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it does not work that way.

First of all, you probably cannot update a version number unless you put in a valid one first.

Secondly, you cannot update and use a version in the same Maven run. Maven uses the versions as they were *at the beginning*  of the Maven run, so changing them in between does not help.

So first run `mvn versions:use-latest-releases` and then run `mvn clean package`.